# Retro sega saturn transparency effect

Tags: mesh, transparency

[image: transparency effect from a sega saturn game]

Is there some way to apply some checkerboard-like transparency effect to 3D mesh similar to this? It's like having a textured mesh but every other pixel is transparent.

And if possible, stay the same size in relation the the pixel of your monitor only, so if you zoom into the mesh or increase the rendered image / video output resolution the pixels remain the same size to your screen pixels only, like the image above.

Btw I'm very new to blender and in still learning stuff so if you could help make an image example, maybe even replicate the effect on a textured cube and send over the .blend file for me to study that would really help a ton!

Comment: Hello, we can't see any image for the moment

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed the image!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *Checker* texture as mix factor between to other textures of your choice for this.

Like say *Transparent* shader and something else for color like an *Emission* (for a shadeless effect) or a *Diffuse*.

[image]

The trick here being using *Window* texture coordinates from the *Input > Texture Coordinates* node for the *Checker*, so it remains aligned to the view.

To get a square aspect ratio you will have to adjust the X scale with a *Vector Mapping* node for the *Checker* texture, and adapt according to your render output resolution.

[image]

Beware that this technique doesn't necessarily pixel align the dithered transparency, nor does it simulate the low resolution aliased object borders. For that you would probably have to actually render at lower resolution. Possibly in a separate render layer and then scale up if you wish to mix it with higher resolution renders for other parts of the scene.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you! I'll give this a go some time after work. One last question, can a texture be mapped to that checkerboard transparent mesh like this pic?

https://imgur.com/gallery/YODB7lE

i was trying to get a texture working on the non-transparent pixels of the checkerboard but didnt get it right.

also is it possible to show the entire node tree you made? 

Comment: You can mix other textures normally into the shaders like any other material. I mistakenly clipped more than I wanted from the node tree, I've added an additional image.